# fail2ban - syntax for setting bantime in a unit other than seconds?

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I have just installed fail2ban on my host.

All documentation I found, including fail2ban's [latest official page](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8), mentions seconds as the time unit to use to ban any given host.

So for example the above page says

> bantime |  600 sec |   Duration (in seconds) for IP to be banned for. Negative number for "permanent" ban.

However `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` shows - both commented and uncommented - such setting as `bantime  = 10m` or `bantime = 1h`

They would appear to be undocumented units of time that can be used instead of specifying just seconds.

Are these new changes? Is there a complete list somewhere or should I just stick to seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version [0.10.0-alpha-1](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/releases/tag/0.10.0a1) (from 2016/07/14) introduced this feature. From the changelog:

> - Enhancements:
>
>   - introduced string to seconds (str2seconds) for configuration entries with time, use `1h` instead of `3600`, `1d` instead of `86400`, etc

The man page for [jail.conf(5)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/man/jail.conf.5) has the up-to-date documentation on this:

> TIME ABBREVIATION FORMAT
>
> The time entries in fail2ban configuration (like `findtime` or `bantime`) can be provided as integer in seconds or as string using special abbreviation format (e. g. `600` is the same as `10m`).

> You can combine multiple tokens in format (separated with space resp. without separator), e. g.: `1y 6mo` or `1d12h30m`.
> Note that tokens `m` as well as `mm` means minutes, for month use abbreviation `mo` or `mon`.
>
> The time format can be tested using `fail2ban-client`:
>
> ```
> fail2ban-client --str2sec 1d12h
> ```

The documentation on the Wiki is ancient. It is for version 0.8 & soon 10 years behind. The [main page](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) of the Wiki even states that:

> Majority of the announcements and discussions is happening on the mailing list and [GitHub](http://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban). G+ users join Google+ and Google+ Fail2Ban Users Community.

Well, as [Google+ is also discontinued](https://plus.google.com/) & the mailing lists have become inactive since the page was last updated in 2016, the development and discussions are now all on [GitHub.com/fail2ban](https://github.com/Fail2Ban).

Comment: Thanks Esa. It's funny that there's virtually no mention of this in any of the Google results. They all (all the ones I found, anyway) mention only seconds.

Comment: In my opinion the Fail2Ban wiki should be closed altogether and replaced with a link to GitHub.